# Why does KCL not work for this node?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

Why does KCL not work at this node?

[image]

From the DC operating point you can see that:
`IR2 + IL1 ≈ 1mA + 2.45uA is not equal to ID1 + IB1 ≈ 0.16mA + 8nA.`

So where does the remaining current goes? 
[Here](https://easyupload.io/deu1mn) is the LTspice file if anyone want to look at it.

Comment: There are three 'problematic' components connected to that node. L1 is zero ohms, or has a hidden finite resistance, but it's small, so might upset the solution through dynamic range / matrix sensitivity issues. D1 and the transistor models will only be approximate. Try putting a reasonable value R in series with L1. Try increasing the bias voltage significantly to reduce the effect of diode law errors. Interesting observation / problem. Solve it by experimenting as I've suggested and you'll learn a lot about simulator errors. I don't believe 8 nA Ib for 870 uA Ic, you shouldn't either!

Comment: The current through C1 is 0.8mA, which makes everything add up, but I don't know why. In a DC operating point analysis, there should be no current there at all. Perhaps there's something happening here (like oscillation) that is preventing convergence to a valid operating point.

Comment: I(C1) <> 0 is DC convergence problem. Some parameters (or methods) should be changed in LTSpice. See this https://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Convergence_problems%3F and this https://groups.io/g/LTspice/message/118250 and this http://www.intusoft.com/articles/converg.pdf

Comment: @Neil_UK Sorry that I forgot to mention the inductor is a real model from LTspice SDR0403-101KL with series resistance 1.9 ohms and parallel resistance 69088.6 ohms.

Comment: Change C1 capacitor type for a real model.

Comment: @G36 it works but why does that work?

Comment: Now, try to delete the C1 capacitor and next try to add a new ideal 100nF cap.

Comment: @G36 that is weird but it works. I don't have any idea why.

Comment: I also don't know why this "trick" solves the problem.

Comment: Did you swap a "resistor shape" with a "capacitor shape" ?

Comment: @Antonio51 what do you mean  "resistor shape"  and  "capacitor shape"?

Comment: The shape, one sees, of the component is a capacitor ... but what the simulator sees is a resistor. I made an error like this some time ago. Try changing the capacitor in a resistor which leads to the current value of 0.8 mA you have seen in the first simulation.

Comment: @Antonio51 I don't think so as I used default components from LTspice library.  I tried the same component different times but somehow the trick G36 mentioned works.

Comment: OK. Trick to absolutely not forget :-)

Answer (score 1):

EE&O ... Somebody to check at lab?

Don't see any problem with the currents. Changing "convergence" methods.
See this for [help](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/rm12.pdf) ... Search "**convergence**" with Acrobat Reader.
There are five basic methods that can be used by **microcap v12**:

- Standard Newton-Raphson
- Source Stepping
- Diagonal Gmin Stepping
- Junction Gmin Stepping
- Pseudo Transient

I add also my used "Global Parameters", in case of need.
Some are related to digital simulation, don't need.

[image]

*** library\MSBJT.LBR
*** NPN General purpose transistor
.MODEL 2N3904 NPN
(BF=326.427 BR=528.632M CJC=3.66441P CJE=4.42095P
IKF=26.7378M IKR=980.247 IS=10.0184F ISC=100P ISE=999.933F ITF=10.1029M
MJC=300M MJE=423.145M NE=1.72338 NF=1.01772 RE=1.47525 TF=477.297P
TR=595.818N VAF=101.811 VJC=700.503M VJE=1 VTF=10 XTF=500.027M)

*** From file mc12cd\library\DIODE.LIB
.MODEL 1N4148 D
(BV=100 CJO=1.337P IBV=100P IS=8N M=316.713M N=2.011 RL=3.521G RS=649.339M TT=8.953N VJ=9.477)

Made with [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip), [new link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ulml1ukc1xv1h2w/mc12cd.zip?dl=0) .

DC Dynamics Analysis (Voltages)
[image]

DC Dynamics Analysis (Currents)
[image]

AC Analysis, working frequency = 989.7 kHz
[image]

TRAN Analysis
[image]

Comment: Nice simulation with microcap v12. I tried 2N222 in LTspice and also got the same problem and this problem is not just on my PC but also happened to some people I know.

Comment: Can you try with "my" model parameters ?

Comment: I just tried and the result is almost same with my original one.

Comment: Can you change the DC "convergence" parameters?

Comment: Tried with 2N2222. All ok. Just frequency change ... 863 kHz.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on which convergence parameters should I change?

Comment: Sorry, don't know well LTSpice. Just use it for already devices available and examples. I can give you my "global" settings, but the names can change, don't know. I add these in answer.

Comment: I just checked and I think LTspice gives less parameters but all parameters in my setting are same as yours except method. I switched to Gear but it doesn't help.